# How to hide custom tabs in My Account section of woocommerce to specific users like subscribers

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have added a custom tab in My Account section of woocommerce which shows statistics of posts from website posted by admin. So how do I hide that specific tab from other users like subscribers/customers.

Comment: How did you add the custom endpoint using a plugin or code?

Comment: Customized code. It is visible directly under dashboard section in my-account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add hooks and filters for adding the custom endpoint only when the user is of a certain role. The following code display the custom endpoint only when the user is either administrator or shop manager.

```
$whitelist_roles = array(
    'administrator',
    'shop_manager'
);

$current_user_role = prefix_get_current_user_roles()[0];

if ( in_array( $current_user_role, $whitelist_roles ) ) {
    // Add rewrite url.
   add_action( 'init', function() {
       add_rewrite_endpoint( 'custom', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES );
   });

   // Add custom menu item to the sidebar.
   add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', function( $items ) { 
       $items['custom'] = esc_html__( 'Custom', 'text-domain' );

       return $items;
   } );

   // Display the content for the custom endpoint.
   add_action( 'woocommerce_account_custom_endpoint', function() {
       echo '<div>Custom Endpoint Data</div>';
   });
}

function prefix_get_current_user_roles() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return array();
    }

    $user  = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles = (array) $user->roles;

    return $roles;
}
```

> P.S. You may need to save the permalink to make it work properly.
>
> P.S. This code will not work if you have assigned multiple roles to a user.